# Getting the parent based on child condition

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am currently working with UI Automation. Now I need to figure out how to get/click the particular radio button. The sample code may look like this:

```
var mainWin = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst
(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty,
"WinTitle"));

AutomationElement radioElement = mainWin.FindFirst
(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "RadioButton"));
```

This will return the first radio button. The problem is that there are more radio buttons placed on the window. One thing I know is that the radio button has the child (label) which have specific NameProperty (e.g: "this is radio button 1"). I would like to get the related radio button based on condition of its child and then use the parent element (radio button) to click on it.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the exact intent that what you want to do here, but we can find the parent element using any of its child element through **TreeWalker** by the following method:

```
TreeWalker tree = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
        AutomationElement ctrl = tree.GetParent(childElement);
          if (ctrl != null)
          {
              // Perform any action
          }
         return ctrl;
```

Hopefully, this will help!